# Draw straight line from start value to end value ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

As always I need your help. I need to draw a straight line from a start value (declared as `SCNVector3`) and connected to the position in the real world till the end point.

Can someone explain to me with some lines of code how can I do it? 
Thank you!

Comment: [This](https://github.com/lapfelix/ARKit-line-drawing) is it.

Comment: I need a straight line not just to draw a line. Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more? What do you mean by connected to the position in the real world till the end point?

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for the question. I have a  touchesBegan function that is starting to monitor the scene and since this function I want to start to draw a straight line until I will remove the finger from the screen and the event will return the line till the last position where I have removed the finger.

Comment: You want 3D line in scene or 2D line on the UIView?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to implement:
`touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`, `touchesCancelled`
for your camera view controller.
In `touchesBegan` you will need to make `hitTest` for current ARFrame in the `UITouch` location. Then you'll have your `startPosition` and your `lastTouch`, which is your start `UITouch`.

Then you will need to add timer with `0.016_667` interval (60Hz) which will update your last touch position with `hitTest` when you camera moves. Same you'll do in `touchesMoved` function. And in `touchesMoved` you'll also update your `lastTouch`. So at this point you'll have your `startPosition` and `currentPosition`, which is `SCNVector3`. And you can just redraw SCNCylinder (with 0.001m radius for example) for those positions if you need straight line.

At last step in `touchesEnded` you'll fix your line, or if `touchesCancelled` you will remove it and clear `lastTouch`.

**UPD**

If you need 2D line on the screen, then you'll need to use `projectPoint` for your ARSceneView.

**3D line drawing**

For drawing 3D line you could `SCNGeometry` use extension:

```
extension SCNGeometry {
    class func line(from vector1: SCNVector3, to vector2: SCNVector3) -> SCNGeometry {
        let indices: [Int32] = [0, 1]
        let source = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: [vector1, vector2])
        let element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .line)
        return SCNGeometry(sources: [source], elements: [element])
    }
}
```

Using:

```
let line = SCNGeometry.line(from: startPosition, to: endPosition)
let lineNode = SCNNode(geometry: line)
lineNode.position = SCNVector3Zero
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lineNode)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I have already a touchesBegan and touchesEnded function, but I haven't really got it how can I draw the SCNCylinder and how the code will understand how to connect the starting point to the end point? I will need to set the node 1 on the touchesBegan with the startPosition and the same but with the second node inside the touchesEnded?

Comment: @PietroMessineo you could try `let line = SCNGeometry.triangleFrom(vector1: startPoint, vector2: startPoint, vector3: endPoint)` and then `let lineNode = SCNNode(geometry: line)`

Comment: There's a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002232/draw-scenekit-object-between-two-points

Comment: Thank you! I will try it asap ;)

Comment: I don't know why but: " Type 'SCNGeometry' has no member 'triangleFrom' "

Comment: @PietroMessineo see updated answer. I forgot that `triangleFrom` was my extension func :)

Comment: How to give custom UI for the line.Like showing tape line instead of the line.